# Can not access rabbitmq management configured in docker even though its status is running

Tags: rabbitmq, dockerhub

I am new docker world and I am attempting to access the RabbitMQ Management plugin on my windows 10. I am following [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/rabbitmq/). But when I try "http://container-ip:15672 " I can not access to management.

Anyone has any experience with such problem?

Comment: What is the error? How do you start the docker image?

Comment: The error is "The page can not be found". I am running it from Kitematic

Comment: Please paste the line for running docker image

Comment: As I said, I am using Kitematic, so I ran rabbitmq from there.

Comment: In the question you said you are following https://hub.docker.com/r/library/rabbitmq/. On that page there are examples for two rabbitmq images being ran; one with and one without management plugin. I just wanted to see which one did you start, because it's could be as simple as you didn't start the right one. Also there are a lot of us here that don't use Kitematic, but do use docker,that's why I was trying to get the answer at the end only to help, but ok..

Comment: I see, I need both, so I ran both of them. but if we ignore management UI, then the command is "docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3"

Comment: I have managed to solve my problem. I was a bit unsure about Docker host IP and container IP. I was trying to use container IP instead of docker host mapped IP.

Comment: Please refer to this thread (Docker version 20.10.12): https://stackoverflow.com/a/72370724/11242070

Answer (score 8):

If you started docker with

```
 docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3-management
```

as described in the reference you mentioned, you might need to add a `-p 15672:15672` to that command line in order to make the management port accessible from the host.

I just ran into the same problem as docker newbie on windows 10 and found that solution [here](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/issues/45).