# How to open rabbitmq in browser using docker container?

Tags: windows, docker, rabbitmq

This was probably asked already, but so far I can't find any detailed explanation at all, and the existing documentation seems as if it was written for some kind on psychic who supposed to know everything.

As per this [manual](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/), I added the container

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:latest
```

Then I checked it to receive the container ip

```
docker inspect some-rabbit
```

Checked ports with

```
docker ps
```

And tried to connect in the browser with this formula

```
https://{container-ip}:{port}
```

It did't work.

Am I'm doing something wrong, or maybe I am supposed to add something additional, like a container for apache or other stuff?

**EDIT**

As I understand, after creating some-rabbit container, now I need to run Dockerfile to create image? (This whole thing is confusing to me). How am I supposed to do that? I mean, I saw command `docker build -f /path/to/a/Dockerfile` but if for example I placed the Dockerfile in second path `D:\Docker\rabbitmq`, how I supposed to get there? (the path doesn't seems to be recognized)

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You are using the wrong image which doesn't have the rabbitmq_management plugin enabled. Change `rabbitmq:latest` to `rabbitmq:management`.

On [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/) they are using the command:

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3-management
```

If you want to go to the UI on `localhost:15672` make sure to expose the port by adding `-p 15672:15672` to the above command.

The management image is just the rabbitmq latest image with the management plugin enabled. Here is the dockerfile for `rabbitmq:management`

```
FROM rabbitmq

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_management

EXPOSE 15671 15672
```

Comment: Still unclear with the Dockerfile, how I supposed to run it at all?
I mean, it supposed to be `docker build -f [path]` but for example I placed it in D:\Docker\rabbitmq\   and here Dockerfile. It seems that I am unable to find it

Comment: @OlegsJasjko Don't build the dockerfile. I just posted it to show you the difference between the `rabbitmq` image and `rabbitmq:management` image. If you want to access UI, just run `rabbitmq:3-management` instead of `rabbitmq:3-latest`. The management image is already built on dockerhub

Comment: Hm, then I still have a problem.
I removed previous container, added new one with -management. Checked if it is started and tried to open localhost:15672 (default port as I understand) and nope, nothing happened, can't open this link

Comment: @OlegsJasjko If you want to use `localhost` make sure to expose the port by adding `-p 15672:15672`, then you can connect to `localhost:15672`. Otherwise, use `<container-ip>:15672`

Comment: Recreated container with port (is there a way to add port to existing one?) and yep, now it works on localhost:15672. But for some reason, it didn't worked with container-ip, could you please add to yours answer words about port? (will accept it anyway, but still it will be more full then)

Comment: maybe management plugin is not enable in your container. so just do this command:  

`docker exec [CONTAINER_NAME] rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`

Answer (score 72):

First off, you need the management image (eg. `rabbitmq:3-management`) to access it through the browser. If your docker is running locally, then you should be able to access it by navigating to `http://localhost:{port}` or `http://127.0.0.1:{port}` (`15672` by default).

Here is an example of a simple `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
 rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - 'rabbitmq_data:/data'

volumes:
  rabbitmq_data:
```

After starting the container, Rabbitmq is now accessible at [`http://127.0.0.1:15672`](http://127.0.0.1:15672). The default username and password should be `guest:guest`. More details [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq).

[image]

Comment: This is not a dockerfile... it's a docker-compose file and the format is not correct.

Comment: This worked for me although I had to use localhost rather than 127.0.0.1

Comment: Weird, exactly the opposite as for @JohnHunt here. `localhost` doesn't resolve, and only `127.0.0.1` works.

Answer (score 66):

Better to expose all three ports (5672, 5673, 15672).

```
docker run -d --name some-rabbit -p 5672:5672 -p 5673:5673 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Then you may browse, http://localhost:15672/ with the credentials "guest" for both the username and the password.

Comment: For me this worked because I just had rabbitmq without management plugin

Answer (score 30):

if you launched rabbitmq by using somthing like:

```
docker run -d --name some-rabbit -p 4369:4369 -p 5671:5671 -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq
```

then you can enable its management plugins while that container runs using the following command:

```
docker container exec -it some-rabbit rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

and the management GUI is running on http://localhost:15672
For management GUI

username: `guest`

password: `guest`

Answer (score 9):

In the current version (20.10.12), I had to pull the latest management plugin enabled image using:

```
docker pull rabbitmq:management
```

Then run with the command (this command does both, pull & run):

```
docker run -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 --name rabbit-image-name rabbitmq:management
```

Navigate to: http://localhost:15672/

It worked!

Make sure you stop the other container images before starting this one.

Comment: After navigating to this URL, I am getting the RabbitMQ login page, But Its showing PAGE UNRESPONSIVE error. any idea or solution why??

Answer (score 6):

The compose would be like

```
version: '3'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq_data
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of http://localhost:15672 you would want to use the ip that your docker instance is running on. 
On windows run:

```
ipconfig
```

Use the ip address as highlighted below:
[image]

Then try http://10.0.75.1:{your-rabbitmq-port}

Answer (score 2):

I use the following command
And in that I defined the username and password
I also exposed ports 5673 and 15673
You need to enter your username and password

```
docker run -d --name same-rabbit \
--hostname my-rabbit \
-e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=USERNAME \
-e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=PASSWORD \
-v /home/USER/rabbitmq/:/var/lib/rabbitmq \
-p 5673:5672 \
-p 15673:15672 \
rabbitmq:management
```

You can also use the following  docker compose

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    rabbitmq:
        container_name: same-rabbit
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=USERNAME
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=PASSWORD
        volumes:
            - '/home/USER/rabbitmq/:/var/lib/rabbitmq'
        ports:
            - '5673:5672'
            - '15673:15672'
        image: 'rabbitmq:management'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.8-management
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_mqtt rabbitmq_federation_management rabbitmq_stomp
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: 'secret cookie here'
VOLUME ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/
EXPOSE 5672 15672
```

1. docker build . -t rabbit-mq
2. docker run -it -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbit-mq

Answer (score 1):

Mapping the ports will do the trick i.e 8085:15672

```
docker run -d --hostname rmq --name rabbit-server 
-p 8085:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

then go to http://localhost:8085/, to access the management console.
**Instead of 8085 you can use any port** available/open in your machine/server.

Please refer [this tuto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0g-1ckQgBo) for more details

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could access the UI of RabbitMQ for several days but some day it suddenly stop working and I can't access it anymore.

After some investigation the source of this problem was found. It was the main service of docker that somehow stopped.

So if you could access the UI and after some time you couldn't, go to your task manager and search for **Docker.Service** to see if it is running, as you can see in the below picture.

[image]

If you don't see it, you should run it manually. 
In my case I have it on my desktop it is called "Docker for Windows".

Answer (score 0):

I see some useful answer, but none as mentioned how to access the server (rabbitmq) using container's ip-address. For people looking for this solution...

- Make sure you have your rabbitmq image running on a container run: `docker inspect`
- [container-id] and scroll down to find the container's ip-address.
- add routing to contain's ip-address see `<

:    [github-issues](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/221)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with version 3, also the article below works on me after giving painstaking trials with 3.8

https://blog.devgenius.io/rabbitmq-with-docker-on-windows-in-30-minutes-172e88bb0808

Answer (score 0):

With Java you may use the lib [Testcontainers RabbitMQ Module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/rabbitmq). An example to bootstrap using Scala:

```
  val rabbitMQContainer = new RabbitMQContainer("rabbitmq:management")
  rabbitMQContainer.start()
  if (os == "mac os x") Process(s"open ${rabbitMQContainer.getHttpUrl}").!
```

and then login with guest:guest

Full example: https://github.com/pbernet/akka_streams_tutorial/blob/master/src/main/scala/alpakka/amqp/AmqpEcho.scala

Answer (score 0):

Please you need to enable the **management plugins**, to be able to access its UI and this by running the following command:

```
docker container exec -it container-name rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Now you should be able access: http://127.0.0.1:15672/

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
If you are running docker container on Remote host and unable to access  URL - > e.g. http://IPaddress:port/15672 , that means docker is running on its own network and you need to share the host machine network with docker container .

you can use this parameter while running your docker run command 

--network host . that will share the network and you will be access to directly access the rabbit management for docker running on remote
```