# open rabbitmq from docker-container in browser

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I create and run rabbitMQ-container, using docker-compose:

```
 version: '3'

 services:

    brocker:
    container_name: rabbit_chat
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    restart: always
    ports:
       - "15671:15671"
```

And tried to open it in browser, using http://localhost:15671

But it doesn't work

PS: answers at [How to open rabbitmq in browser using docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290108/how-to-open-rabbitmq-in-browser-using-docker-container)  not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exposed container port is 15672, not 15671.